# Printer prints blank pages Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: printing, 22.10

I have a Konica Minolta Pagepro 1580MF ad recently i switched to Ubuntu 22.10 from WIndows 11 and i couldnt print a document sucessfully. Ubuntu automatically installed a driver for it but when I try to print it keeps on printing blank pages. Please help

Comment: How do you print? Ubuntu has a long-standing bug in CUPS where everything you want to print as text via the command line comes out blank. Also, for hardware issues, it pays to use the latest (23.10), even if it's just for tests.